# Should generated documentation go in version control history?

Tags: version-control, documentation-generation

I'm against compiled stuff going into version control, specially when it comes to compiled binaries, however, my principles are now in question after adding doxygen support for a project.

Should the hundreds of files generated by doxygen go into version control?, what is the recommended practice here?, I think the ideal would be automating the process in a server that publishes that documentation at the same time, however, there is no such server now nor there will be for some time.

Comment: Ask yourself: What value does it add, and what does it cost? In general, it clutters repo history forever, and builds (including the documentation) should be reproducable by a single command anyway, so there ought to be little value. Plus, you can host the documentation on a shared network drive or something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.

Keep everything that you need to rebuild anything else. If it's auto-generated then you can go back to any point in the history of your repository and build it again. Why keep it?

Comment: Bingo.  Anything you can generate should be treated like object code and should go away when you `make clean`.